# HSA and Concierge Medicine

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, hsa

I currently have a high deductible healthcare plan and max out my HSA. I am looking for a primary care doctor and have decided to use a concierge doctor. On the doctor's website it says:

> Insurance does not cover the cost of a concierge medicine fee. It is an out-of-pocket expensive. However, healthcare saving accounts such as HSA and FSA can be used towards the cost.

However, when I have googled if this cost is HSA eligible I find all sorts of conflicting information. Even with a concierge doctor I will not be changing my health insurance and plan on keeping my HDHP and contributing to my HSA. How do I find out if the fee is actually eligible to be reimbursed or not?

Answer (score 2):

The expenses eligible for HSA are generally the same expenses eligible for deduction. The HSA-related [IRS Pub. 969](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969#en_US_2022_publink1000204083) refers to the [IRS Pub. 502](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p502#en_US_2022_publink1000178887) on deductible expenses for that matter.

It is unclear what "concierge medicine fee" means. Is it some kind of plan administration fee? Additional insurance cost? Club membership fee? From [this article](https://www.partnermd.com/blog/concierge-medicine-costs-factors-considerations) it seems to be a membership fee, and I'm not sure if it would be deductible as such. The [IRS Pub 502](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p502#en_US_2022_publink1000179057) explicitly lists "Health club dues" as not allowable.

Without knowing exactly what that means, it's hard to decide whether it is an allowable expense or not. You may want your tax adviser go over this with you.

Comment: Thanks, it says on the site, "In a Concierge Medicine Model, an extended service fee is charged to patients, which covers the cost of patient care management not covered by insurance, such as increased access and availability." Basically you pay a fixed amount per year and get unlimited access to your doctor. You pay for things like labs but not office visits, telehealth visits, you have electronic messaging with your doctor for free, etc.

Comment: @user1723699 Yeah, I'm not sure if that's not what "health club" describes in the instructions. You're not paying for treating a specific condition, which is probably going to make it not allowable. Unless they can frame themselves as an HMO, you're probably out of luck

Comment: Thanks, I figure I'll just save my receipts anyway, by the time I'd ever reimburse myself I'll have a CPA for my taxes so I'll run it by them then. It is just quite confusing when a google search can bring up a lot of conflicting information

Comment: Health club, in the US, usually means exercise facility or something like it. But checking the exact definition might be a good thing. Outside of that: I've never experienced any significant difficult getting to see my PCP when I need to, so I'm still confused about what this program is providing. But I've always been on a corporate health plan, and am currently looking toward a company-sponsored Medicare Plus plan which seems to have roughly similar coverage, so I admit I may be spoiled compared to most Americans. (We need a health system. We have a health insurance system. Not even close.)

Comment: @keshlam It's bringing an HMO model to a wider group. A _capitated_ HMO plan pays a primary care physician a monthly per-patient fee, which covers office visits and some basic services like labs and x-rays. The doctor gets a more constant revenue stream (typically, flu season is a huge peak and summer is a low) and is incentivized for preventive care (nagging you to take flu shots). "Concierge" is basically the same thing but out-of-pocket to the patient. A sign you are under a capitated plan is that you're required to select a PCP and report it to the health plan.

Comment: True HMOs are indeed a Good Thing; a friend who works for a university is on one and I've envied her coverage. Unfortunately there are a lot of things claiming to be HMOs that are really PPOs with a small provider pool, and which aren't good at admitting that referral to an outside specialist when necessary has to be part of that model.